# Why is OpenGL telling me I've used GL_STATIC_DRAW when I've specified otherwise?

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, graphics

When I have the debug layer on with OpenGL, I register a callback, that gets called whenever there's anything of note to tell me. It seems not all the messages that are passed to the callback are errors. There's an "OTHER" category, and it seems it outputs these messages whenever you've done something. In my case I create a VBO with:

```
GLuint VBO_ID;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_ID); // The VBO_ID I get back is 3.
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_ID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeInBytes, vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
// At this point the callback is called, which gives the message:
```

> message: Buffer detailed info: Buffer object 3 (bound to
>   GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, usage hint is GL_STATIC_DRAW) will use VIDEO
>   memory as the source for buffer object operations.

No matter what the usage hint (last argument of glBufferData), this message ALWAYS says the usage hint is `GL_STATIC_DRAW`. No matter whether I use `GL_DYNAMIC_COPY`, `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW`, `GL_STATIC_READ`, anything. The message is always the same.

So yeah, I'm really confused about this. Also why does it give this message, it's not a warning as I haven't done anything wrong, it's just a confirmation. I've ended disabling this "OTHER" category of messages otherwise my log just gets filled with these, because it's called whenever I do something.

Comment: If the debugging layer is polling from the graphics card or the driver implementation somehow, it could be that the implementation is ignoring the hint altogether (I think AMD is doing this, not sure about Intel and Nvidia) and just returns GL_STATIC_DRAW as a default value.

Comment: @CollapsedMargin I see. My card is an Nvidia GTX980

Comment: @Zebrafish: Debug messages are all implementation-defined. As such, we can't really know why your implementation is giving you that message (or why it says `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB`, when `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` has been core OpenGL for over a decade.)

Comment: GL_STATIC_DRAW or GL_DYNAMIC_COPY is kind of hint to drivers. Driver while looking at your data access pattern may decide there is no need to put his data in special area. As by specifying Dynamic copy you are telling driver my buffer present on cpu might modify many times so I will update it and resend it many times but If your data is not modifying say per draw call driver might just decide to put it in location comfortable to driver and overrride your request. Its just kind of optimization done by driver thats what confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Nvidia driver is very verbose if you enable low severity/info/other, feel free to disable those
2. As stated by others, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY is only a hint and driver is free to ignore it.
3. Depending on your access pattern to buffer you might see message stating buffer was recreated in different location (host memory, DMA)

Don't worry about that constant, just put GL_STATIC_DRAW. Its leftover from old GL versions. You can also use glBufferStorage where you can more precisely specify buffer usage.